# Call a method of a different class in base class method

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//can't modify it
class Orig{
    public:
    void Method(){
        cout << "I am original method";
    }
};

class Mock{

  public:
  void Method(){
      cout << "I am  mock method";
  }
};


//can't modify it
class UseMethod{
    Orig object;

    public:
    void UseOrigMethod(){
        object.Method();
    }
};

class UseMethodMock : public UseMethod{
   //some code
};

int main()
{
    UseMethodMock o;
    o.UseOrigMethod();
}
```

I want to call `Method()` of `Mock` class using above code when I call `o.UseOrigMethod();` from main. I have tried declaring `object` of `Mock` class in `UseMethodMock` but still it uses `Orig`'s object.

Is there any way we can fool compiler and call `Mock`'s `Method` when it calls `object.Method()` in `UseMethod` class?

I can change code in `Mock` and `UseMethodMock` classes but not in others.

Comment: Just override the function in `UseMethodMock`?

Comment: Can't do that. I am writing unit test for `UseOrigMethod()`.

Comment: But if you change the way `UseOrigMethod()` works, you are not really testing it.

Comment: You are right! But in `UseOrigMethod()`, I need to fake this call as it is not what I need to test but the rest code of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shame in modifying code to make it more testable, so maybe you can reconsider. In this case:

1. Prepare `Orig` for inheritance by making its methods virtual.
2. Inject an `Orig` instance into `UseMethod` via its constructor (beware slicing – pass by pointer or reference).
3. Have `Mock` inherit from `Orig` and override the virtual methods.

If the performance of virtual calls is a concern, do it all at compile time:

1. Make `UseMethod` a template, that takes the type of `Orig` as a template parameter.
2. In production code, use `UseMethod<Orig>`.
3. In test code, use `UseMethod<Mock>`.

If you really, absolutely, positively can definitely, certainly not modify `Orig` and `UseMethod`, you can abuse the preprocessor:

```
#include "Orig.h"
#define Orig Mock
#include "UseMethod.h"
#undef Orig
```

Of course, this comes with a whole boatload of caveats (most notably, it assumes that `UseMethod.cpp` does not refer explicitly to the `Orig` type), and in general I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: I think I have to take pre-processor way as I do not have the liberty to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call orig's method. You should override useOrigMethod() in UseMethodMock class.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the UseMethod class Orig object to Moke object i will give expected output it means called the method of Moke class.

**code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//can't modify it
class Orig{
    public:
    void Method(){
        cout << "I am original method";
    }
};

class Mock{

  public:
  void Method(){
      cout << "I am  mock method";
  }
};


//can't modify it
class UseMethod{
    //need to change here Orig to Moke
    Mock object;

    public:
    void UseOrigMethod(){
        object.Method();
    }
};

class UseMethodMock : public UseMethod{
   //some code
};

int main()
{
    UseMethodMock o;
    o.UseOrigMethod();
}
```

**output**

```
I am  mock method
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.006435 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I wish I could do it but I am not authorized to change it. :(